# API calls from one angular service is not being intercepted by jwt -interceptor - while all others are ok

Tags: angular-http-interceptors

In my angular-ionic app I have several services calling REST apis in the backend.
All API calls are intercepted by jwt-interceptor and bearer token is being added except 1 .
The funny thing is that one method (getVehicles) is begin intercepted correctly while the concerned method (createVehicle) is not being intercepted. Any ideas?

Pls find code for my service

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { VehicleModel } from '../models/vehicle.model';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { Criteria } from 'src/app/common/model/criteria.model';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class VehicleService {
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  criteria: Criteria;
  vehicle: VehicleModel;
  baseUrl = environment.API_URL + '/api/vehicles';
  vehicleRegistrationNumber: string;

  // List of vehicles
  public getVehicles(criteria: Criteria): Observable<VehicleModel[]> {
    return this.httpClient.post<VehicleModel[]>(this.baseUrl + '/search', criteria);
  }

  // Create a new item
  public createVehicle(vehicle: VehicleModel): Observable<VehicleModel> {
    return this.httpClient.post<VehicleModel>(this.baseUrl + '/createVehicle', vehicle);
  }

  // Edit vehicle details
  public updateVehicle(vehicle: VehicleModel): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.put<VehicleModel>(
      this.baseUrl + '/updateVehicle', vehicle);
  }
}


and code for jwt-inteceptor:

    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AuthenticationService } from '@/_shared/_services';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class JwtInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) { }

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        // add authorization header with jwt token if available
        const currentUser = this.authenticationService.currentUserValue;
        if (currentUser && currentUser.token) {
            request = request.clone({
                setHeaders: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${currentUser.token}`
                }
            });
        }
        return next.handle(request);
    }
}
```